# Django/ python validate JSON

Tags: python, django, json, django-models, django-forms

what is the best way to validate JSON data in Django/python.

Is it best to create a bunch of classes like the Django FormMixin classes that can validate the data/ parameters being passed in?

What's the best DRY way of doing this? Are there existing apps that I can leverage?

I'd like to take in JSON data and perform some actions/ updates to my model instances as a result. The data I'm taking in is not user generated - that is they are id's and flags (no text) so I don't want to use Forms.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean - do you want to validate a string and ensure it is valid JSON? Do you want to take a JSON object and make sure that datatypes are correct (e.g. data.intVal is an integer value)? Or something else?

Comment: I want to ensure that they are valid data types...but also ensure that it contains the correct key,value pairs. But I want a generic DRY way of doing this since the key,value pairs that need to be there will vary based on which model I'm processing. Similar to the way Django Forms are.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just instantiate a model object from the json data and call full_clean() on the model to validate: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean

```
m = myModel(**jsondata)
m.full_clean()
```

Answer (score 4):

[validictory](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/validictory/0.4.2) validates json to a json-schema. It works. Of course, now you need to define your schema in json which may be a little much for what you want to do, but it does have it's place.

Comment: pretty decent library. Well worth checking out

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a python library named DictShield for this https://github.com/j2labs/dictshield

DictShield is a database-agnostic modeling system. It provides a way to model, validate and reshape data easily.

There is even a sample for doing JSON validation:

**Validating User Input**

Let's say we get this JSON string from a user.

{"bio": "Python, Erlang and guitars!", "secret": "e8b5d682452313a6142c10b045a9a135", "name": "J2D2"}

We might write some server code that looks like this:

```
json_string = request.get_arg('data')
user_input = json.loads(json_string)
user.validate(**user_input)
```

Comment: Dictshield seems very nice, but from its description it is a library to model data (and also has validation) not just validate it.