# How to validate a json structure in Python3

Tags: python, json, django, validation

I am using Python3.5 and Django for a web api.When I refer to input, I refer to a HTTP request parameters. I have a parameter where I am expecting a JSON data which I need to validate before processing further.

I have a base json structure that the input has to be in.
Example,

```
{
  "error": "bool",
  "data": [
      {
        "name": "string",
        "age": "number"
      },
      {
        "name": "string",
        "age": "number"
      },
      ...
    ]
}
```

The above `JSON` represents the structure that I want my input to be in. The keys are predefined, and the value represents the datatype of that key that I am expecting. I came across a Python library([jsonschema](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonschema)) that does this validation, but I can't find any documentation where it works with dynamic data. i.e. the objects inside the JSON array 'data' can be of any number, of course this is the most simple scenario I came up with for explaining the basic requirement. In cases like these, how can I validate my `json`?

The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975124/django-python-validate-json) didn't help because it's just checking if the json is proper or not based on the Django model. My json has no relation with Django model. Its a simple json structure. It still doesn't tell me how to validate dynamic object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django/ python validate JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975124/django-python-validate-json)

Comment: @AjaySingh No, the solution there, just checking if the json is proper or not based on the Django model. My json has no relation with Django model. Its a simple json structure. It still doesn't tell me how to validate dynamic object.

Answer (score 7):

JSON Schema is a specification for validating JSON; jsonschema is just a Python library that implements it. It certainly does allow you to specify that a key can contain any number of elements.

An example of a JSON Schema that validates your code might be:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "required": [
    "error",
    "data"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "error": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "data": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "age": {
            "type": "integer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

See https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/ for a good overview

Comment: This looks legit, I will try it out tomorrow and get back. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't `false` be surrounded by quotes?

Comment: No, why should it be? It's a Boolean, not a string; the bool values in JavaScript (and json) are `true` and `false`.

Comment: I was asking because I tried to build the schema to validate against, and `false` doesn't quite work in Py. :D

Comment: If you construct this as a Python dict, you'll need to use Python types, so it will be `False`. When you dump it to json, it'll be converted to `false`.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look into the documentation of [Python's JSON API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html). I believe `json.tool` is what you're looking for, however there are a couple of other ways to validate JSON using that API.

Comment: Lemmi have a look.

Comment: The json.tool seems to only check if the json is of valid python's json format. The question here is to validate based on a predefined json structure with possible keys and corresponding possible values.